# Format date like: Monday, 1st March

Tags: python, django, date, date-formatting

Seems like it should be simple enough but it's driving me up the wall. I've looked at the python date formatting strings and it still doesn't make too much sense.

Here's what I'm trying to do: `<Full day>, <Day of month><Ordinal> <Month>`

Where `<Ordinal>` is `st`, `nd`, `rd`, `th`, etc depending on the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2**: Looks like OP found this useful after all :)

**Update**: Never mind. The OP was looking for *Django* date formatting, not Python.

AFAIK there is no built in format specifier for the ordinal. The others are easy:

```
my_date.strftime('%A, %d %B')
```

I found [this solution](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/155606-time-formatting-date-suffixes) on the web:

```
if 4 <= day <= 20 or 24 <= day <= 30:
    suffix = "th"
else:
    suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][day % 10 - 1]
```

Comment: This is still very much relevant to my interests. I do process dates behind the scenes (in Python) too.

Answer (score 4):

Just found the answer [in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#now). God knows why they're not linked to from every reference to date formatting.

```
{{e.when|date:"l, jS F"}}
```

Outside of templates:

```
from django.utils import dateformat
dateformat.format(datetime.now(), 'l, jS F')
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want `{{ e.when|date:"l, jS F" }}` instead.

Comment: Aha. Django's date formatting differs from Python's. Do you mind editing your question to say that you are looking for something Django specific?